# document.write() not working in wordpress header.php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

A javascript function which performs a document.write() works fine when called within a WordPress post body, but does nothing when called from within header.php template in WordPress.

Any suggestions on how to have document.write() work from within WordPress' header.php?

switchads(); contains a document.write() command.
Called within header.php, the function runs, but document.write() produces no change to the page.

This snippet shows how the function (located in adtest.js) is called within header.php and it does not output HTML (in a post body, it does):

```
        <div id="ad1">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="adtest.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
            switchads();
            //--><!]]></script>
        </div>
```

javascript function being called contains a document.write():

```
function switchads() {
  document.write (
    '<div>random html here</div>'
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your console? Are there any errors? Have you got an adblocker running?

Comment: It hasn't been necessary to protect scripts with CDATA blocks for a very long time.

Comment: First, let's add a `console.log` under `document.write` to ensure your code is actually running.